# Content isn't displayed unless commented and then uncommented

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am working with an expansion panel that makes an API call when clicked, populating the `v-card` and `v-layout` with the response data. The challenge I am facing is that initially, the `v-layout` isn't populated.

If I comment out the `v-flex` elements, the `v-layout` will generate and display the expected number of rows (that are now empty and blank). Then, I uncomment the `v-flex` which displays the data properly within the `v-layout`.

Below is the template code I am using, alongside the API call that is being used when the `v-expansion-panel-content` is clicked:

```js
<v-expansion-panel expand>
  <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(device, index) in devices" :key="index">
    <div slot="header" @click="requestDeviceBreadcrumbs(device.id);">
      <v-card flat>
        <v-layout row wrap class="pa-3 project" :class="inAlarm(device)">
          <v-flex xs12 md6>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Location</div>
            <div>{{ device.location }}</div>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Address</div>
            <div>{{ device.ip_address }}:{{ device.http_port_number }}</div>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Manufacturer</div>
            <div>{{ device.manufacturer }}</div>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs2 sm4 md2>
            <div class="right">
              <v-chip small class="white--text caption my-2" :class="inAlarm(device)">
                {{ device.alarm_count }}
              </v-chip>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </div>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-layout row wrap class="pa-3 project" v-for="(breadcrumb, index) in device.breadcrumbs" :key="index" >
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <div class="caption grey--text">Oid</div>
          <div>{{ breadcrumb.oid }}</div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6 sm4 md3>
          <div class="caption grey--text">Value</div>
          <div>{{ breadcrumb.value }}</div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6 sm4 md3>
          <div class="caption grey--text">Timestamp</div>
          <div>{{ breadcrumb.timestamp }}</div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
    </v-card>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

And my API request function:

```js
requestDeviceBreadcrumbs: function(device_id) {
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/breadcrumbs/?device=${device_id}`
  }).then(response => {
    this.devices.find(obj => obj.id === device_id).breadcrumbs =
      response.data;
  });
}
```

My concern is that it's taking too long for the API to respond, is this the case? If so, what is acceptable way of handling this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your component code, especially `data` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)** to add/update a reactive property to one `device`:

```js
requestDeviceBreadcrumbs: function(device_id) {
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/breadcrumbs/?device=${device_id}`
  }).then(response => {
    let device = this.devices.find(obj => obj.id === device_id)
    this.$set(device, 'breacrumbs', response.data)
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: There's a typo in `this.$set(device, 'breacrumbs', response.data)`. Needed to be 'breadcrumbs'. Works, thank you.